# This is an OpenID we haven't seen before

Tags: support, openid

My account works pretty well on the other three sites.

But when I log on to Super User, I get:

> This is an OpenID we haven't seen before: [openid]

What gives?

Answer (score 8):

Don't worry about it. Go on and create a new account. Then, in the accounts tab of your profile, associate your SU account with one of your other accounts and you can copy your profile information over.

Comment: it's very misleading this way, isn't it? is it a bug?

Comment: I wouldn't consider it a bug. After all, you really are creating a new account, so the language is correct. It's just that people were used to the old system where the site recognized an OpenID from a different site.

Answer (score 7):

We improved the message so it now says

> This is an OpenID we haven't seen on {website name} before:

But Kyle's answer, above is 100% correct.

Answer (score 2):

As of June 2018, openid is being depreciated on the network so its unlikely that a user will see this error message.