# Remove OpenID Question from FAQ?

Tags: discussion, faq-update-request

The Stack Exchange network has deprecated OpenID and on July 1, 2018 users will [no longer be allowed to logon via this authentication method](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307647/271445).

Given this, should we remove the question [This is an OpenID we haven't seen before](https://meta.superuser.com/q/39/213131) from the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)?

Or do we not maintain questions tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) given it's been replaced with the Help Center?

Comment: I think you mean "will deprecate OpenID" because it's only May 22nd, 2018.

Comment: No, I do mean deprecate. While OpenID logons are still allowed its looming termination clearly makes its use discouraged, i.e. depricated.

Comment: It should be stated that OpenID has not been deprecated yet, they have not even sent out the emails, which were supposed to be sent out in May.  The announcement banner also has not been displayed.  We can add a warning about the depreciation in July but to remove it a month and a half early, seems premature.

Comment: I think it would be premature to remove the question while OpenID is still in use. Presumable it would be appropriate to remove it after 1 July 2018.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed the FAQ tag.

Not awake enough to decide if it should be closed and how.

Have posted answer pointing out its depreciated